# how to use R Verification Package for seasonal climate prediction data set

Tags: r, verification

I want to use the `verification` package in R.  I have daily data of obs and prediction in the following format:

- Obs data has dimension of 120, 396 where 120 is the lead time and 396 is the total initial time.
- Prediction data has dimension of 120, 396, 10 where first two dimensions are same as obs data dimension and the third dimension is of ensemble member.

Also, I already removed daily climatology mean from my data. To get probabilistic skill, I need to change my obs data into binary data set and prediction data into probabilities. For that I need to use the verify function in the `verification` package in R (I think my understanding is right). But when I apply this function, it gives some error as

```
If baseline is not included, baseline values  will be calculated from the sample obs.

Error in e1[[1L]] : subscript out of bounds
```

In addition:

#### Warning messages:

1. `In is.finite(obs) & is.finite(pred) :
   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`
2. `In max(pred) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf`
3. `In min(pred) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf`

I do not know how to solve this function. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: Please give a smaller example of your dataset, and the code you tried to use?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried working through the [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/verification/vignettes/verification.pdf)?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem of reading the data and got some plots from verification package of `R`. Now I want to know that how to arrange data in `R` i.e. I arranged the observation data like (120, 396) where 120 is the lead time and 396 is the total initial time. The forecast data has one extra dimension of ensemble member like (120, 396,10). Before putting these data sets into verify function of verification package, I do like this

```
obs <- round(runif(100))
forecast <- runif(100)
```

I do not know why this process is necessary and what it does but it is necessary before putting into verify function. Then to use verify function I use,

```
verify(obs, forecast, obs.type = "binary", frcst.type="prob")
```

Then everything is OK and I can use the result of verify function to other things. But I do not know how verification package works and my data arrangement is correct? Which dimension is taken as sample dimension in above data set 120, 396?